# Raspberry PI 4 (Window 11 OS) I2C LCD Display Module program not compiling (C# Dot Net 4.7)

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am new to Raspberry Pi. I am trying the sample program of 2 Line LCD display module using I2C with C# Dot Net 4.7. I am using Windows 11 Home edition on Raspberry Pi 4B (8GB) module.
I have got this sample from Microsoft site. I am getting the comiplation error while implementing at my development environment as below line:
new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Logical, driver));

Error : Program.cs(23,53,23,67): error CS1729: 'GpioController' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments because of Constructure take one parameter.

Please help me how to fix this one. Can anybody share the correct program in Dot Net C# for LCD module.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/dotnet-iot-assets/blob/main/tutorials/LcdTutorial/Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Device.I2c;
using System.Threading;
using Iot.Device.CharacterLcd;
using Iot.Device.Pcx857x;

namespace DisplayI2CModule
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Displaying current time. Press Ctrl+C to end.");
            I2cDevice i2c = I2cDevice.Create(new I2cConnectionSettings(1, 0x27));
            var driver = new Pcf8574(i2c);
            var lcd = new Lcd2004(registerSelectPin: 0,
                                    enablePin: 2,
                                    dataPins: new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
                                    backlightPin: 3,
                                    backlightBrightness: 0.1f,
                                    readWritePin: 1,
                                    ***controller: new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Logical, driver));***
            int currentLine = 0; 
            
            while (true)
            {
                lcd.Clear();
                lcd.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLine);
                lcd.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
                currentLine = (currentLine == 3) ? 0 : currentLine + 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

ST

Comment: Are you compiling on Windows or Raspberry?  The compiler on windows is different from linux.  What is error?

Comment: Hi I am compiling on WIndows 10 OS then will copy into Raspberry PI WIndows 11 by Pan Drive. I am getting the error at new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Logical, driver).  This take only one argument the PinNumberingScheme numberingScheme not the driver.

Comment: There is something wrong with the types in the parameter list.  See if changing to Pcf8574 driver = new Pcf8574(i2c); gives different error message.  If you right click GpioController and then select go to definition you will see the overloads and parameters list.  One of the types is not correct.

Comment: I have already gone to the GPIO defination. It accept only one parameter.  If I pass one paramenter like GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Logical) then how would I add the I2C driver. I am using PCF8574A LCD Display Unit. I have got it in Raspberry toolkit.

Comment: There must be more than one overload in the definition.  Look at the rows above and below the one that is selected.  Let me do some checking.  You do not necessarily need a driver. Specifying the port number should be enough with the hardware. The compiler may need to driver to do error checking.

Comment: Why Net 4.7?  Looked at source code at GitHub.  Should be correct.  Download latest library.  Green Code button has a zip.  https://github.com/dotnet/iot

Comment: This is for dotnet core (dotnet 6), it won't work on .Net Framework 4.7.

Comment: Hi the defination of the GPIO function as below ;
  public GpioController()  {        }
and    public GpioController(PinNumberingScheme numberingScheme)
            : this()
        {
            NumberingScheme = numberingScheme;
        }

I have use it with my other existing device application. That application have compile in Dot Net 4.7. I can not use for Dot Net 5.o and above. I have a limitation. SO I need to use the .Net 4.7 only.